# Reductive Lie Groups and Complexification

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be a complex Lie group (not necessarily connected) with reductive Lie algebra $\frak{g}$. (We may assume that $G$ has finitely many connected components and is linear-algebraic.) Of course, $G$ need not be the complexification of a compact Lie group (ex. $G=\mathbb{C}$). To what extent, however, is $G$ "close" to being the complexification of a compact Lie group? Does $G$ belong to some kind of extension involving the complexification of a compact Lie group? Is $G$ some reasonably nice quotient of the complexification of a compact Lie group? I would appreciate any answers to questions of this nature. Also, I would appreciate any and all references.

Thanks!

Comment: The functor $G \rightarrow G(\mathbf{C})$ is an equivalence from linear algebraic $\mathbf{C}$-groups $G$ with reductive $G^0$ to complex Lie groups $H$ with reductive Lie algebra and finite $\pi_0(H)$ such that $Z_{H^0}$ is a power of $\mathbf{C}^{\times}$. For any such $H$ and maximal compact subgroup $K$, denote by $K'$ the unique linear algebraic $\mathbf{R}$-group with $K'(\mathbf{R})=K$ meeting every component of $K'$. Then $K'(\mathbf{C})=H$ and $H$ is the complexification of $K'$ as defined in Bourbaki. See D.3.2 and D.3.3 in the Luminy notes on reductive group schemes (use Google).

Comment: @PDC: The expression *reductive Lie group* in the header already raises questions about how you would define this notion.   For linear algebraic groups the concept depends on the Jordan decomposition rather than the Lie algebra.   Your 1-dimensional example shows the complication here, while your earlier question is relevant:
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/124418/

Comment: Correction to my previous comment:  I should have written $Z^0_{H^0}$ rather than $Z_{H^0}$. 

Comment: 

     These are good points. For me, the relevant notion of reductivity for complex Lie groups is that of linear reductivity (or equivalently, being the complexification of a compact Lie group). Is the issue with example $G=\mathbb{C}$ in some sense the only way that $G$ can fail to be the complexification of a compact Lie group? Are there any structure theorems for complex Lie groups $G$ with reductive Lie algebras that relate such groups $G$ to linearly reductive groups?

Comment: Also, Professor Humphreys, might you provide me with a reference for your earlier comment that a reductive algebraic group in characteristic zero is an almost-direct product of a central torus and a derived subgroup? 

Comment: @PDC: Concerning your reference request, the definition of "reductive" algebraic group is uniform for all characteristics and is found in textbooks like mine *Linear Algebraic Groups*, 19.5 and Chapter X.  The initial definition just requires the unipotent radical to be trivial, but the detailed inner structure comes later on.  The 1965 paper *Groupes reductifs* by Borel-Tits is a basic source.

Comment: @PDC:  There are *commutative* compact complex Lie groups which have nothing to do with linear algebraic groups, namely the "complex tori" in the sense of $V/L$ for a finite-dimensional complex vector space $V$ and full rank lattice $L$ in $V$.  So the structure of the center needs to be brought out in the analytic theory to "rule out" problematic cases.  The description I gave with the Lie algebra and the center (and a bit for the component group) seems as "good" as one can hope to say over $\mathbf{C}$ (life is harder over $\mathbf{R}$), or maybe someone else has a better idea...

Comment: @user28172 Is it not true that a (possibly disconnected) complex linear algebraic group is reductive if and only if it is the complexification of a compact Lie group? (and if this is true, are the conditions you gave in terms of finite $\pi_0$ and $Z_{H^0}^0$ being a power of $\mathbb{C}^\times$ $equivalent$ to $H$ being the complexification of a compact Lie group?)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $ G $ is a connected affine algebraic group over $ \mathbb C $.  Then there is a short exact sequence $ 1 \rightarrow U \rightarrow G \rightarrow L \rightarrow 1 $, where $ U $ is the unipotent radical of $ G $.  $ L $ is a reductive group, i.e. the complexification of a connected compact Lie group.  $ U $ is a unipotent group: a successive extension of copies of $\mathbb C $ (the additive group).

On the Lie algebra level, we have a similar extension $ 0 \rightarrow \mathfrak u \rightarrow \mathfrak g \rightarrow \mathfrak l \rightarrow 0 $.

Now, the question assumes that $ \mathfrak g $ is reductive, which means that $ \mathfrak u $ is an abelian Lie algebra and thus $ U = \mathbb C^n $.  Also the fact that $ \mathfrak g $ is reductive means that the extension splits and we have $ \mathfrak g = \mathfrak u \oplus \mathfrak l $.  I think that this implies that $ G = L \times \mathbb C^n $.

So if my reasoning is correct, then any connected $ G $ with reductive Lie algebra is just the product of a reductive group with $ \mathbb C^n $.

(If $ G $ is disconnected, the situation is more complicated.  For example, suppose we have a finite group $ L $ which acts linearly on $ \mathbb C^n $.  Then we can form the semidirect product $ G = L \ltimes \mathbb C^n $.  It's Lie algebra will be just abelian and thus reductive, but $ G $ is not a product.)

Comment: If the Lie algebra is reductive, it must be the direct sum of a semisimple Lie algebra and its *center* = radical (one of Bourbaki's equivalent conditions).   This is stronger than just having an abelian unipotent radical in the group $G$.